# MySQL - edge case use of GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

My understanding of GROUP BY is that its standard use is to aggregate items. So a typical example might be:

```
select 

count(id),
department,

from table
group by department
```

The above would a count of all id's per department.

So, I got taught a very useful (but possible pretty dodgy!) trick using group by. I was wondering if this usage has any problems. Although the query runs as expected [results as expected in all cases], my spidey sense is tingling a bit...

Imagine the following data set:

```
id  |  user_id  |  cost  |  note
----------------------------------
1         1         120     Test 1
2         1         150     Test 2
3         2         100     Test 3
4         3         120     Test 4
```

Now if we do the following SQL:

```
select * from table
group by user_id
```

You get the following result set.

```
id  |  user_id  |  cost  |  note
----------------------------------
1         1         120     Test 1
3         2         100     Test 3
4         3         120     Test 4
```

The query runs apparently as follows:

- run through the table
- when a groupable user id is found, ignore the subsequent ones
- return this table of unique user_id items

Effectively I get a "unique", with specific boundaries and I am able to select * from this list.
Furthermore, by ordering the table prior to the order by, I can use this to filter all costs.

So - this is also as you'd expect.. BUT:

In the ABOVE example - Say I actually ensured that for user_id 1, the value 120 was shown (as opposed to it's other possible values - 150 in this case). Then 120 seems to be guaranteed to be the response. 
The approach could be then to sort by some order alphabetical/numeric/other advanced filters etc... THEN use this sort to force the first item in the table to be the "answer".

The actual query I want to do is pretty complex. Using MIN or similar are not suitable for the end value I want... However: this "order your table then take the first unique item using group by" approach is actually quite elegant (I think).
I am actually using group by constrained across 4 fields, and this, combined with other SQL makes a CORRECT answer.

So. After that long background: a question!

All documentation I have used only talks about using group by with aggregate functions. I can't seem to find the behaviour of JUST group by.
This strikes me as one of two things:

- a correct (mis)use case that's not been documented
- an accidental behaviour of whichever version of mySQL I'm using.

So... which one is it?
If it's a correct, but edge case, behaviour, then great. If I'm tricking the SQL engine to spit something out, then I've got no proof this is compatible with future versions so I'd be uneasy to use it.

Cheers in advance all.

Comment: Note that `select * from table group by user_id` is (outside of MySQL) invalid SQL. For more details why, read this: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Go through this MYSQL Documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html  other columns not used in the group by are choose by the server randomly by the server so there is no fixed sequence for that...

Comment: See - I don't know what "randomly" means. There must be a method to its choice... and that's what I need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this through the above links/help, I think it's unfortunately the case that: while the answer is correct, it's not guaranteed to be correct... More accurately it is "indeterminate".

I am genuinely confident following my repeated successful use of this that the internal workings are "first come first show", but as the spec also says this isn't guaranteed so I can't rely on it.

Cheers for help all. Have up-voted all comments.

Answer (score 4):

In other `RDMS` you cannot use `GROUP BY` clause without aggregate function on fields that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause and this makes sense since those fields need to be aggregated (min,max,count etc) but in mysql it lets you use fields without any aggregate function and it will show you the first value encountered for that field.
This behavior of mysql has pros and cons :
  - pros: you can use this to get the first value encountered for that field
  - cons: if you are not aware of this behavior you can get corrupt results